# How can I password protect a page and all posts in that page with WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress 3.5 and I want to have a page http://mysite.com/media be password protected. Once you get to the page (with the correct password), all of the posts on that page should be available to you. If, however, you land on a post without a password, it will prompt you for a password.

Is this possible to do natively or are there plugins that I would need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/) to require registration - the best way to control site access by login and password - and to also disable the RSS feed, so your site doesn't offer a feed.

Comment: I don't want to require registration. Just want a few posts and one page to be password protected.